# disable few cells in recycleView from swipe or hide delete while swiping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have a custom recycleView with swipe to delete option. I am able to display custom recycleView and also delete the item by swipping it. Swipe to delete is implement by using a separate class which implements SimpleCallback. Now, i want to disable the swipe to delete or dont show delete button while swipping for few items based on the username displaying in the RecycleView.

```
public class SwipeHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

SwipeHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        final View foregroundView = ((Adapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).viewforeground;

        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((Adapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).viewforeground;
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final View foregroundView = ((Adapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).viewforeground;
    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                        int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((Adapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).viewforeground;

    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
}

public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
    void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
}
```

}

And how I implemented

```
   ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new SwipeHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Viewholder in recycleView.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView uname,time,comm;
    CircleImageView civ;
    RelativeLayout viewBackground,viewforeground;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        civ = (CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        uname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        comm = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
        viewBackground = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
        viewforeground = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);

    }
}
```

Now i want to disable the swipe for the username which is not matching with uname in viewholder. I searched SO they ask to do change in SwipeDirs method but there i am not able to get the viewHolder values inside of it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Override `getMovementFlags` in your ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback to check the view holder for the conditions that permit swiping as follows:

```
@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final int dragFlags = 0;
        final int swipeFlags;
        swipeFlags = ([OK to swipe this view]) 
            ? ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END
            : 0;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }
}
```